# Disable Javascript on WebEdit Link in experience editor

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8.1, experience-editor

We are on sitecore 8.1 update 3.

Is it possible to disable "javascript" on WebEdit:EditLink popup on Experience editor.

[image: Experience Editor - showing insert link]

We already have custom General Link which already removes "javascript" from content editor. How can we do this on Experience editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The window you see there comes from this XML file:
`/sitecore/shell/Applications/Dialogs/GeneralLink/GeneralLink.xml`

The javascript block you want to remove looks like this.

```xml
<Border ID="JavaScript">
  <a href="#" class="mode" onclick="javascript:return scForm.invoke('OnModeChange','javascript')" onfocus="this.blur()">
    <ThemedImage Class="mode-icon" Src="Software/32x32/text_code_javascript.png" />
    <div class="mode-text">
      <Literal Text="JavaScript"/>
    </div>
 </a>
</Border>
```

Comment: How is this GeneralLink.xml is connected to "chrome:field:editcontrol({command:"webedit:editlink"})" ?

Comment: Look for "webedit:editlink" in file "Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config". It will point out to a class in a dll. If you disassemble that one, you will find this "urlString["xmlcontrol"] = "GeneralLink"